# Shopify: launch FB retargeting on specific page

Tags: facebook, shopify

I'm trying to launch a Facebook retargeting script on a specific page within the blog on shopify: (/blogs/blog/URL)

I'm using this script in the theme.liquid file:

```
{% if page.url == '/blogs/blog/URL' %}


<script>(function() {
var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
if (!_fbq.loaded) {
var fbds = document.createElement('script');
fbds.async = true;
fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
_fbq.loaded = true;
 }
_fbq.push(['addPixelId', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX']);
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
window._fbq.push(['track', 'PixelInitialized', {}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?    id=624847270968156&amp;ev=PixelInitialized" /></noscript>


{% endif %}
```

The theme.liquid file saves fine, but the code doesn't show up in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because blogs contain [articles](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/article), not [pages](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-documentation/objects/page).

Try this instead:

```
{% if article.url == '/blogs/blog/URL' %}
```

[A snippet like this](https://github.com/joshuacc/Shopify-Snippets/blob/master/find-current-url.liquid) can be useful in this kind of situation:

```
{% assign current_url = '' %}
{% case template %}
  {% when 'page' %}
    {% assign current_url = page.url %}
  {% when 'blog' %}
    {% assign current_url = blog.url %}
  {% when 'article' %}
    {% assign current_url = article.url %}
  {% when 'collection' %}
    {% assign current_url = collection.url %}
  {% when 'product' %}
    {% assign current_url = product.url %}
{% endcase %}
```